# Modifier vs function call

Tags: solidity, modifiers, function

What is more gas efficient and secure, using a modifier(for example only owner) or calling a function to verify state(calling a function that returns owner address and compares that to the address that called a function)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-security: both are equally secure

-gas efficient, read from [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/solidity-gas-optimizations-and-tricks-2bcee0f9f1f2) the chapter named "Use Modifiers Instead of Functions To Save Gas". For me is an insignificant gas difference. I strongly recommend using modifiers or internal functions to improve code visibility.

I usually use modifiers to verify the input or to sandwich the code.